# How to include people with disabilities in your gym

Tags: exercise, gym, health

The last time you had a disabled person in your gym? If you're like most owners of fitness companies, it's probably been a long time. How can you handle this situation?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is off-topic as we can't control the amount of disabled people in our gyms (unless we're the owner and questions involving owning a gym are off-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about marketing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of disabled people don't want to go to the gym or don't feel the need, you can't force people to go to the gym because it's inviting for the disabled.

The gym I go to has many disabled people use it. Just because the gym you own/go to doesn't, doesn't mean the rest of the gyms in the world do not.

> how can you handle this situation?

I'm guessing your gym is lacking members therefore you're looking to target a "niche" market. You can't simply appeal to disabled gym goers as you will likely miss out a massive amount of the market. If you specifically hold classes for disabled people then you'll end up insulting someone. There is no feasible way that you can continue to appeal to your common gym user and a disabled gym user at the same time. At the same time you're also not taking into account mental disabilities, ones you can't see. Have you thought about that?